# Upper and Lower Limits

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Define

$\limsup_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=\sup\{ m: \exists x_n\rightarrow 0 \text{ s.t. }f(x_n)\rightarrow m\}$

My question is, does this limit always exist? If so, why?

Further, how do I show that if

$\limsup_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=\sup\{ m: \exists x_n\rightarrow 0 \text{ s.t. }f(x_n)\rightarrow m\}$ and$\limsup_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=\inf\{ m: \exists x_n\rightarrow 0 \text{ s.t. }f(x_n)\rightarrow m\}$

exist and are equal then $lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)$ exists and is equal to the common value above? I know that the equality of the supremum and infimum implies that the set is a singleton, so denote it by $m$. But what $\delta$ should I take to show that the limit is equal to m?

Comment: As an extended real number, yes.

Comment: What about in the standard real line?

Comment: No, then, there may not be such a real number. For instance, for $\ln x$ the RHS is $\sup\emptyset$, which either you take to be the extended real number $-\infty$ or you admit not to exist in $\Bbb R$. Also, it must be clear that the LHS reads $\limsup\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).